# Nested checkbox in ngbTabTitle not working

Tags: checkbox, tabs, ng-bootstrap, ng-template

I'm trying to put a checkbox in a tabset title, but it doens't seem to work. I really appreciate some help. My simplified code look like this:

```
    <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab>
            <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedTabs" (click)="selectTab(i)" />
                Result
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedTabs" (click)="selectTab()" />
                ...
```

The model is being changed as I can see in the second "test-checkbox" and the console, but the activation-state is not shown by the checkbox in the title. Does anybody has an idea how this can going to work, please?

regards,
Lars

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the event handling in `ng-boostrap`'s tab selection that is interfering with the checkbox selection (when the checkbox is in the header). To get around this, you can pass `$event` into the `(click)` handler for the checkbox and call `event.stopPropagation();`:

**HTML**

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedTabs" (click)="selectTab($event)" />
      Result
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedTabs" />
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  ...
</ngb-tabset>
```

**Typescript**

```
public selectTab(event): void {
    this.selectedTabs = !this.selectedTabs;
    console.log(this.selectedTabs)
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevents event propogation and the checkbox is selected/deselected
}
```

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wg3zsf?file=app/tabset-basic.html) for a demo.